# How do you "Drop down to Assembly"?

Tags: c++, objective-c, optimization, assembly

Sometimes when I'm reading stuff, usually in C++ / Ojective-C, I see people say that for speed increase (etc), if necessary, you as the programmer can drop down to Assembly. How do you actually do that? Do you write some Assembly and compile it, and then... ? How do you link the two together? Do you have to link the objects together when linking? Could someone provide an example, maybe of the main function of a simple C++ hello app calling, say a function written in Assembly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It differs by compiler, but in Visual C++:

```
__asm
{
    int 3;
}
```

Which triggers the debug-interrupt.  Everything enclosed in that `__asm` block is, well, assembler.

Comment: Yes, inline assembly is compiler specific. Here's a guide to the GCC syntax: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: It might also be good to note that VC doesn't support inline assembly when targeting 64-bit output.

Comment: So, will that actually generate an int, usable outside of the scope of the Assembly block?

Comment: @Josh: No. That `int` means "interrupt" (i.e. x86's `int` instruction), not "integer".

Comment: Ah, well is there a way to actually do things like operate on declared variables? Or is the Assembly execution confined to its scope? And sorry about the int, I had a feeling it meant something else, I've only just dabbled in Assembly.

Comment: The GCC Link I posted above has some examples under "Recipes" which manipulate C variables outside the scope of the asm block

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, most compilers allow for inline assembler. Some assemblers produce object files that are compatible with those produced by a related C++ compiler which it can then link with it's linker.

However, typically, inline assembler produces a speed decrease, not a speed increase. This is because the compiler has no optimization information about what's going on in the assembler block, and a modern compiler typically produces faster assembler than written by a human hand. Most assembly language functionality is available in C++, either through direct language features or intrinsics (like the Interlocked intrinsics in Visual Studio).

Comment: actually, the assembler extensions in g++ tell the compiler what is coming in, what is going out, and allow the compiler to decide which registers to use, and how to preserve state.

Comment: The concept that the compiler produces better assembler than the human is a wild overgeneralization.  The compiler is better than the human at bookkeeping, at deciding register usage.  But for a custom section of code that computes more efficiently using special instructions, or exposing instructions that are not supported in default C++ (like rotate), the compiler is completely hamstrung.

Comment: @Dov: Depends on the compiler. The OP doesn't specify his compiler. And any decent compiler will provide extensions for the full platform-specific usage. It's an extremely rare piece of code that is more efficient when hand-written if compiled with a current generation compiler.

Comment: @DeadMG Obviously, if someone asks about "dropping down to assembler" they are talking about specific sections of code, not entire applications.  So if we take, for example, someone who wants to take an int and rotate it, or take an int and find the highest bit set, I am not aware of a single compiler on the intel platform that will recognize the C/C++ code and generate the right instruction.  Are you trying to tell me that if you write:

   inline int ror(int x) { return x >> 1 | x << 31; }
that your compiler will recognize the ror instruction? If so, tell me what compiler you are using

Comment: @Dov: OK, great, you saved two whole instructions. The time spent would be better saving dynamic allocations, or something that actually takes up a meaningful amount of time. Unless your entire program is composed of right rotates. In which case- you could just use the intrinsic that my compiler does indeed provide, which does produce the ror instruction.

Comment: @deadmg snide non-answer aside, what is your compiler, how do you use these intrinsics?  The typical use is math, like this: http://locklessinc.com/articles/mandelbrot/ or the latest from intel: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/3d-vector-normalization-using-256-bit-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-intel-avx/.  Got intrinsics for those?

Comment: @Dov: I use MSVC10, and I don't use them at all, but that's not the point. I do have intrinsics for SSE2, and as for the Sandy Bridge extensions, then nobody has a CPU that could even run any intrinsics I could have, or any inline assembler you could write, so it's really a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  asm { trap };
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is compiler specific.